# Jquery min and max show new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to validate myForm, so the user can input a value between 1 and a max on 99. When I submit a number I get showed a blank page, which is the select.php. But I would like to stay on my indexpage, and get the message "You are below". Can anyone see what is wrong here?

index.html:

```
<div class="content">
        <p id="number"></p>
        <div class="form">


                <form id="myForm" action="select.php" method="post">
                    <input type="number" name="numbervalue" id="numberinput">
                    <input type="submit" id="sub" Value="Submit">
                    <span id="result"></span>
                    <span id="testnumber"></span>
                </form> 

        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    var minNumberValue = 1;
var maxNumberValue = 99;

$('#sub').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var numberValue = $('input[name=numbervalue]').val();
    if(isNaN(numberValue) || numberValue == ''){
    $('#testnumber').text('Please enter a number.')
    return false;
  }
  else if(numberValue < minNumberValue){
    $('#testnumber').text('You are below.')
    return false;
  }
  else if(numberValue > maxNumberValue){
    $('#testnumber').text('You are above.')
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});


// Insert function for number
function clearInput() {
    $("#myForm :input").each( function() {
         $(this).val('');
    });
}

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#sub").click( function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); // remove default action(submitting the form) 
       $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
         function(info){            
         $("#result").html(info);
       });
       clearInput();
    });
    });



// Recieve data from database
$(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval(function () {
        $('.latestnumbers').load('response.php')
      }, 3000);
    });
```

Comment: Are you using the validation plugin from jqueryvalidation.org?

Comment: ops no :-/ Good point. Do I have to use that plugin, or can I find a code where I am not depended on that plugin?

Comment: you can write a validation function that is called on submit of the form and if the validation fails (number not in the expected range), you should return false (and therefore stopping the submit with that)
[link](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little function to validate the number:

```
var minNumberValue = 1;
var maxNumberValue = 99;

$('#sub').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var numberValue = $('input[name=numbervalue]').val();
    if(isNaN(numberValue) || numberValue == ''){
    $('#result').text('Please enter a number.')
    return false;
  }
  else if(numberValue < minNumberValue){
    $('#result').text('You are below.')
    return false;
  }
  else if(numberValue > maxNumberValue){
    $('#result').text('You are above.')
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```

You can define the minimum and maximum values by changing the two variables (be sure to check these server-side too if you are submitting to a server, as the user could manipulate the code via dev tools to change these boundaries or submit whatever they want).

The result message is displayed in your `span#result`, otherwise you could use `alert()` too.

The important things here are the `e` parameter in the click function (it's the JavaScript event), calling `e.preventDefault()` (if you don't do this, the form will submit before finishing validation, as the default action for an `input[type=submit]` is to submit a form [go figure...]), returning `false` whenever the conditions aren't met, and returning `true` if it satisfies the validation. The `return true;` allows the form to follow its action parameter.

And a fiddle with this: https://jsfiddle.net/3tkms7vn/ (edit: forgot to mention, I commented out `return true;` and replaced it with a call to add a message to `span#result` just to prevent submission on jsfiddle.)

Comment: Cool thanks a lot. I am at work right now, so I will test the code when I come home, and then give points for your answer :)

Comment: I was just reading your answer. My number is saved in a MySQL database. That means I have to do some serversite to? Do you have a link where I can read a little more about that, or do you know what I have to add to the code.

Comment: Yea, you'll need a server-side language to accept the post parameters (in php $_POST['numbervalue'] will contain your number), and you can verify that it's greater than 1 and less than 99 on the server; if not, then return an error to the user, and use JavaScript to display the message. If successful, use JavaScript to inform the user. You'll want to know how to respond to AJAX requests - whether in plain text, xml or JSON. I prefer JSON - https://www.html5andbeyond.com/jquery-ajax-json-php/.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your big answer. I just have one last question, before I close the question. I have updated my qestion with your code. When I run the code, I can still put in fx 200 and I get the response on 200. I cannot figure out where it goes wrong. My span id="testnumber", does not give me anything. Do you have a clue where the error is?

Comment: Sorry, been off for a few days. You've now got two click listeners for #sub, you should only use the one. Instead of returning true in the one from my answer, replace that with your form submission function (so if validation passes, it performs the AJAX submission). If you were submitting like normal (where the client is redirected to the action parameter - instead of using AJAX), you would return true; however, if you are using AJAX to submit the form information, just do that instead of returning true.

Answer (score 2):

How about utilizing the '**min**' and '**max**' attributes of the **input** tag, it would handle all the validation itself:

```
<input type="number" name="numbervalue" min="1" max="99">
```

Cheers,

Comment: not all of us are outside corporate environments and can ignore IE 7 8 and 9; even without MS support packs... http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp